# SED: replace string with another string

Tags: awk, sed

I am new to scripting looking for help to replace `<buildWrappers/>` with `<buildWrappers> Sample text </buildWrappers>`

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should edit your question so that the information you have in the title is included in the body as well as showing us the code you're using that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace string with another string in `sed`:

```
sed 's/replace_this/replace_with/g' 
# g is to replace all occurences of replace_this
```

For your particular case:

```
sed 's@<buildWrappers/>@<buildWrappers> Sample text </buildWrappers>@g' file
```

To change the file in place:

```
sed --in-place ...
```

You will need to escape special chars (if any in sample text). Those special chars are: `@` (delimiter) `& \`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jahid.
I want to replace <buildWrappers/> with below changes.
  <buildWrappers>
    <org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper plugin="artifactory@2.3.0">
      <tagPrefix></tagPrefix>
      <releaseBranchPrefix>REL-BRANCH-</releaseBranchPrefix>
      <targetRemoteName></targetRemoteName>
      <alternativeGoals></alternativeGoals>
      <defaultVersioning>GLOBAL</defaultVersioning>
    </org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper>
  </buildWrappers>

Comment: ticked the mark, can you pls give me a command for my second request.

Comment: @venkat  `sed 's#<buildWrappers/>#<buildWrappers> <org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper plugin="artifactory@2.3.0"> <tagPrefix></tagPrefix> <releaseBranchPrefix>REL-BRANCH-</releaseBranchPrefix> <targetRemoteName></targetRemoteName> <alternativeGoals></alternativeGoals> <defaultVersioning>GLOBAL</defaultVersioning> </org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper> </buildWrappers>#g' file`

Comment: @venkat used `#` as the delimiter to avoid escaping `@`

Comment: Thank you Jahid. It worked. I want to Keep it in Html tag format